# Eclipse Drupal XDebug breakpoints not working on .module

Tags: eclipse, drupal-7, xdebug, breakpoints

I have successfully configured [Xdebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdebug) with Eclipse, and now I'm able to set breakpoints on the `index.php` file.

When I set breakpoints other then `index.php`, file breakpoints don't work. If the file is in same folder, it stops on first line but breakpoints don't work after resume.

Comment: More to add... breakpoints are working with   xdebug_break();
but not by placing through editor...

Comment: successfully solved : by removing path variable in php server configuration of eclipse

Comment: You can write an answer to your own question with the information that you provided in the prior [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150877/eclipse-drupal-xdebug-breakpoints-not-working-on-module#comment14621385_11150877).

Answer (score 1):

First :
 breakpoints are working with xdebug_break(); but not by placing through editor...
Secondly:
by removing path variable in php server configuration of eclipse

Issue was resolved